# Applescript trouble with moving files in script

Tags: applescript, move

this is the script I'm trying to use:

```
on open thisItem
set this_folder to (the POSIX path of thisItem)
set export_folder to "Macintosh HD:Users:j****.*******:Desktop:AUTOMATOR:export"
set pdf_folder to "Macintosh HD:Users:j****.*****:Desktop:AUTOMATOR:PDF"
tell application "Adobe Illustrator" to open thisItem
tell application "Adobe Illustrator" to save current document in export_folder as pdf with options {class:PDF save options, PDF preset:"Low res proofing"}
tell application "Adobe Illustrator" to close current document
tell application "UltraLowPDF" to open
tell application "Finder" to move every file of folder "Macintosh HD:Users:j*****.*****:Desktop:AUTOMATOR:PDF" to container of this_folder
```

end open

This script should do a few things:
1. It creates a pdf file from an .ai file using adobe illustrator.
2. It then runs that pdf file through an automator workflow, which then spits out a pdf into a folder on my desktop.
3. It then moves that pdf file from the desktop, back to the folder of the original .ai file.

Every part of the script works fine except for step 3, it just seems to ignore it entirely. I've tried adding a delay, thinking the script was getting ahead of itself.

I've also tried isolating the move part of the script, using this droplet:

```
on open thisItem
set this_folder to (the POSIX path of thisItem)
tell application "Finder" to move every file of folder "Macintosh HD:Users:j****.******:Desktop:AUTOMATOR:PDF" to container of this_folder
```

end open

But this just throws up an error saying that it can't get the «class ctnr» of the file dropped on it (-1728).

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

(note: I've starred out the user name part of the filepath for privacy)

EDIT: It seems that it's the Automator part of the script that is the problem, (the ''UltralowPDF"" app). After this runs, nothing after it in the script will run.

Comment: `this_folder` (last word of your script) is a POSIX form, whereas you need the colon-separated form - I think you need `thisItem`.

Comment: this doesn't work either :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `thisItem` is actually `theseItems` (aka a list). Either you need a repeat loop or – as in the following code – get the first item of the list.

The Finder does not accept (slash separated) POSIX paths. It works only with (colon separated) HFS paths.

The script uses the relative path `path to desktop` which point always to the desktop of the current user.

```
on open theseItems
    set automatorFolder to (path to desktop as text) & "AUTOMATOR:"
    set thisItem to item 1 of theseItems

    set export_folder to automatorFolder & "export:"
    set pdf_folder to automatorFolder & "PDF:"
    tell application "Adobe Illustrator" to open thisItem
    tell application "Adobe Illustrator" to save current document in export_folder as pdf with options {class:PDF save options, PDF preset:"Low res proofing"}
    tell application "Adobe Illustrator" to close current document
    tell application "UltraLowPDF" to open
    tell application "Finder" to move every file of folder pdf_folder to container of thisItem
end open
```